# How to prevent click handler for a specific target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using these to make clickable link row but I don't want to include the checkbox because I am using checkbox to filter another action.

Is it possible to except checkbox on the row?

How to prevent click handler for a specific target

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
    window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table_adj table-checkable txt-col mar_bot_10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input class="mail-group-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="movetofilter"> <span></span>
        </label>
      </th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th><span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Added Reference">b</span>
      </th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th><span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Received Message">e</span>
      </th>
      <th><span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Received Date">f</span>
      </th>
      <th>g</th>
      <th>h</th>
      <th class="text-right">i</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='http://stackoverflow.com'>
      <td>
        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
          <input class="mail-group-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="movetofilter"> <span></span>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>1
      </td>
      <td class="text70px">1</td>
      <td class="text170px">1</td>
      <td>212</td>
      <td class="text40px">23</td>
      <td class="text70px">2</td>
      <td class="text40px">4</td>
      <td class="text70px">5</td>
      <td class="text70px text-right">6</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Add you html code please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Show us the html of a row

Comment: Sorry for that - i have just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify what element was clicked using `event.target`.

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
    // Check if target is NOT inside '.mt-checkbox'
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.mt-checkbox').length){
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    }
});
```

Comment: @kris, you should have left the html in the question for future readers to make sense of my answer. Also, consider accepting answers if they solve your problems by clicking the check mark besides them.

Comment: Oh sorry Alexandru Serverin -  i will try to add that again